# Retrieve form.errors from views and print to the console

Tags: django

I want to print the error if the form is valid

```
form = TagForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid(): 
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')
else:
    print(form)
```

However,it throw messages less useful,

```
<tr><th><label for="id_name">Name:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul><input type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" required id="id_name" /></td></tr>
```

I am aware of the error message could be displayed on template

```
{% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
        ...
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
    ....
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

How could retrieve them from views.py and print to console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `print(form)`, use `print(form.errors)`.

Surprisingly, in the title of the question you've correctly mentioned `form.errors`.

See docs about [`Form.errors`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors).