# django form errors not showing on template

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-validation, django-errors

I'm using the basic django registration form and I'm not getting any errors displayed. I've seen a bunch of answers and nothing is working for me. I'm not sure if it's because I have custom css for the page or bootstrap or something else. Basically how do I display the errors in this particular case.

Here's my form:

```
<div class="form-content">
  <h1>Sign Up</h1>
  {% if user.is_authenticated == False %}

  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %} {{form.as_p}} 
    <button class="btn form-btn">Sign Up</button>
    <h4><span>or</span></h4>
    <a
      class="btn google-btn"
      href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}"
      role="button"
      style="text-transform: none; width: 100%"
    >
      <img
        width="20px"
        style="margin-bottom: 3px; margin-right: 5px"
        alt="Google sign-in"
        src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/512px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png"
      />
      Sign up with Google
    </a>
  </form>
  {% else %}
  <p>You're already registered...</p>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Here's my view:

```
class UserRegistration(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = RegisterForm
    template_name = 'registration/registration.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        form.registration_notification()
        login(self.request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
        return redirect(self.request.GET.get('next'))
```

and form:

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

    def registration_notification(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if self.is_valid():
            registration_notification_task.delay(email, username)
```

I'm not sure where to return the errors or where to validate the form and no answers for other questions have helped my situation. Now when I submit an invalid form there are no errors the page just doesn't submit. There's not even an error in the network tab so it's probably happening on the html side.

Comment: Can you print out the error and see  if the console says something? Look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51334641/retrieve-form-errors-from-views-and-print-to-the-console

Comment: nothing is printed, the form isn't invalid it isn't even attempting to submit

Answer (score 0):

Updating my post following comments below:

`**forms.py**` (dont forget the import bit)

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm

class  RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email", "password1", "password2",]
```

**views.py**

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            new_user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                                    password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],)
            login(request, new_user)
            messages.success(request,("Registration succesful!"))
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/home")
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request,'main/registration/register_user.html',{'form':form})
```

**registration template**

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 mx-auto">
              <div id="second">
                  <div class="myform form ">
                        <div class="logo mb-3">
                           <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                              <h1 >Signup</h1>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                         <form method="POST" action = "{% url 'register_user' %}" class="form-group">
                              {% csrf_token %}
                                {{ form| crispy }}
                                   
                           <div class="col-md-12 text-center mb-3">
                              <button type="submit" class=" btn btn-block mybtn btn-primary tx-tfm">Let's do it!</button>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-12 ">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                 <p class="text-center"><a href="{% url 'login_user' %}" id="signin">Already have an account?</a></p>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                     </div>
            </div>

         {% endblock %}
```

Comment: that doesn't help. No errors pop up the page just auto scrolls to the first required field.

Comment: I dont think I help you more. I am surprised no one has found an answer. Usually when the forms scrolls back up to a required filed it's because it's not complete. Unless you are trying to work on this specific template, I am happy to copy and paste mine if tat can help.

Comment: sure ill take a look

Comment: I have edited my post above. Have a look. Hope that helps!